# PHP include html by option

Tags: php, html, include

I need to include html, not from file, just simple code.
I have main content included by:

```
<?php
$content = array(
    '001'=>'content/001_001.php',
    '002'=>'content/001_002.php',
    '003'=>'content/001_003.php'
);
if(in_array($_GET['show'], array_keys($content))) {
    include($content[$_GET['show']]);
} else {
    include('content/001_001.php');
}
?>
```

And on a side i'd like to include simple html, but that's more like 3 buttons in each category, so cloning lots of *.html & *.php files won't be right and clean work.

In case of opened page: `?show=001`, on a side would be added `<div>001</div>;`
`?show=002`, on a side would be added `<div>002</div>` and etc.

Comment: actually don't get you..

Comment: point of not adding code from file, coz it's shortness to clone lots of files to be included. And include pure html instead of "content/001_001.php"

Comment: Do you want to have something like if ($_GET["show"] == 002) { include "example.php"; } else { include "example2.php"; } ? Of course you can use a elseif.

Comment: Question is not clear, pls add more information to the question (not in comment).

Comment: Ok, for example if you have (?show=001) it includes code from ('001'=>'content/001_001.php',) and i need it to add code not by including page with code, but have something like: ('001'=>'here should be pure html, not included page',) like ('001'=>'some text & [div]text[/div]',) hope it's better :)

Comment: Why are you not doing it like that then? I think there is no other way than you told us about right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to load HTML code from an array rather than from a file. You can do this by changing your **include** to **echo**.

```
<?php
    $content = array(
        '001'=>'<div><a href="#">001</a></div>',
        '002'=>'<div>002</div>',
        '003'=>'<div>003</div>'
    );
    if(!empty($_GET['show']) && isset($content[$_GET['show']])) {
        echo $content[$_GET['show']];
    } else {
        echo $content['001'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Yeap, looks like what i need! Cheers! But one thing, when i'm opening index.php by default it should show '001', but it's not.

Comment: It worked for me as: (... if(in_array($_GET['show'], array_keys($content))) {echo($content[$_GET['show']]); } else {echo('deposit');}...) It right, or ..?

Comment: The code works just fine for me, what does your array look like?

Comment: Ahh... just og it, in case of none is selected or wrong ?show=... it shows content by ID (echo $content['001'];) >> from '001'. And i've tried to use simple text in (echo $content['001'];)